# C to MIPS trouble

Tags: c, assembly, mips

So I have been working on this for a few days now, and I have managed to get through all of it except one part is getting me.

```
int mystery(int a0)
{
    if (a0 == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return mystery(a0 - 1) + a0;
    }
}
```

I have this recursive function and I have some MIPS code. The C code works but I have a problem somewhere in my MIPS code that is making it not come out correctly beyond putting in 2.

```
.text

main:

li $a0, 2
jal mystery
move $a0, $v0
jal putDec
li $a0, '\n'
li $v0, 11
syscall

li $a0, 3
jal mystery
move $a0, $v0
jal putDec
li $a0, '\n'
li $v0, 11
syscall

li  $v0, 10     
syscall

putDec: 
    li $v0, 1
    syscall 
    jr  $ra     

mystery: 
 bne $0, $a0, recur 
 li $v0, 0      
 jr $ra             

  recur: 
sub $sp, $sp, 8     
sw $ra, 4($sp)  
sub $a0, $a0, 1
jal mystery         
sw $v0, 0($sp)  
jal mystery         
lw $t0, 0($sp)  
addu $v0, $v0, $t0  
addu $v0, $v0, 1    
add $a0, $a0, 1     
lw $ra, 4($sp)  
add $sp, $sp, 8     
jr $ra
```

Everything up to the label 'mystery' is fine it is just there as a formality to actually put in arguments and print after. The problem I am having is getting values above 3 to print out the right numbers. Help would be greatly appreciated if someone could see where I am making my mistake. Thank you

Comment: What happened when you ran this in the debugger?

Comment: Seems right to post this on Stack overflow. NB: the Ackerman funtion will probably be faster.

Comment: When I run this in MARs it prints 3 and 7.

Comment: If it is any help I changed the line "li $v0, 11" in putDec to "li $v0, 1" (was a mistake) also when 3 is put in as the argument is should print 6 I believe and not 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoo after extensive work and tracking the code one step at a time I think I finally got it, had to do quite a bit of changing but actually seems easier now. Here is the code in case you want to look over it again, if you can see a problem that could arise with any certain values I did not test. Thanks for the help all.

New recursive mystery function:

```
mystery: 
 bne $0, $a0, recur     
 li $v0, 0      
 jr $ra             

 recur: 
  sub $sp, $sp, 8   
  sw $ra, 4($sp)    
  sw $a0, 0($sp)
  sub $a0, $a0, 1   
  jal mystery       
  lw $t0, 0($sp)    #
  addu $v0, $v0, $t0    
  lw $ra, 4($sp)    
  add $sp, $sp, 8   
  jr $ra
```

Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try taking a step back, and comparing the *structure* of the C and assembly code, without worrying too much about the details.

In the C code, there is a conditional, leading to either a base case (which just returns a value) or the recursive case.  The recursive case performs a subtraction, the recursive call to `mystery`, and an addition.

Now look at the assembly version: this, too, has a conditional leading to either a base case or a recursive case.  But look at the structure of the recursive case: there are *two* recursive calls to `mystery` there!  That's a strong hint that it's unlikely to be doing the same thing...

Comment: +1 Because you seem to understand something that most SO skulls of mush do not: answering questions like this should be a moment for education, not a moment for gaining a simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

you're suppose to return the ASCII symbol, change  "li $v0, 1" in putDec to "li $v0, 11" (that was not a mistake)

Comment: Yes initially that is what I needed to do but to better understand the underlying concept it was easier to view it as a decimal. From there I could check which ascii characters would be represented by that number. This made it easier to figure out problems and check for correctness in the code. Then I just needed to change the system call value back to 11 when I was sure everything else was correct.